# Prove that, if both solutions of ${ x }^{ 2 }+ax+b=0$ are even integers, then a and b are both even integers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that, if both solutions of$${ x }^{ 2 }+ax+b=0$$are even integers, then a and b are both even integers.

I don't even know where to start on this problem.

Comment: Well, the proof that $b$ is even is pretty easy. Do you know any results or theorems that might be helpful? What have you tried, and what are you having trouble with?

Comment: Write $x^2+ax+b=(x-2k)(x-2s)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)=x^2-(x_1+x_2)x+x_1x_2.$$Hence, $a=x_1+x_2$ and $b=x_1x_2$ are even integers, because $x_1$ and $x_2$ are even integers (these are the roots).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\alpha$ is an even solution, you get:

$\alpha^2 + a\alpha + b =0$

You can write as

$b= -\alpha^2 - a\alpha$

so $b$ is sum of two even integers and it's even!

Now suppose the other solution is $\beta$:

$\beta^2 + a\beta + b =0$

take the difference of the two equations to eliminate $b$:

$(\alpha^2 - \beta^2) + a(\alpha -\beta)=0$

divide by $\alpha - \beta$:

$(\alpha + \beta) +a= 0$

i.e.

$a= -(\alpha + \beta)$

so $a$ is sum of two even integers and it's an even integer.

When $\alpha = \beta$ it is a solution of the derivative $p'(x)$ i.e.

$2\alpha + a = 0$

i.e.

$a= -2\alpha$.